# How to return a value from a function with Excel.run()?

Tags: excel, office-js

How can I return a value from this function. I'm having to write a callback as a work around. I'd like to be able to write utility functions such as below that will use Excel.run() and return the needed value as a function output.

```
function currentSheetName() {        
    //How to return a value from this function. For eg: activeWorksheet.name


    Excel.run(function (ctx) {
        var activeWorksheet = ctx.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
        activeWorksheet.load("name");

        return ctx.sync().then(function(){
            callback(activeWorksheet.name)
        });

        }).then(function() {

        }).catch(function() {

        }); 
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Good question!  Several possible solutions.

One solution is to use typescript and `async/await`, and be able to side-step the problem altogether.

Another is set a pass-through variable in your `context.sync()` call, or do a `return` in a `.then` -- and the value will get passed through.  It will also flow out into caller of `Excel.run`, such that you can do an `await` or a `.then(function(result) { ... })` and have access to that value.

For the latter, see the following screenshot from the book "[Building Office Add-ins using Office.js](https://leanpub.com/buildingofficeaddins)" (full disclosure, I am author of said book, but I do think you'll learn a lot from it, and I have no personal profit from it as I donate 100% of its profits to charity).  The screenshot shows passing values between `.then`-s, but it's the same concept for just returning the value out of the `Excel.run`.

[image: Value pass-through]

In terms of using TypeScript and `async/await`, there's a bunch of guidance on it in the book as well (the JS portion is actually in the appendix, as the book reflects my personal viewpoint that starting with TypeScript 2.0 and `async/await` in particular, the best way to experience and use our Office.js APIs **is** through TypeScript).